How to extract full monitor manufacturer/vendor ID in Windows? (as same as Linux hwinfo --monitor command)
I´m stuck with extracting hardware information of my monitor manufacturer ID in this format: xxxxx_xxxxxxx
Basically, format which provides Linux command hwinfo --monitor as "vendor" parameter seems impossible to reach in standard .NET/PowerShell classes or Win APIs.
Seems like most of .NET instruments provide only limited data about monitor IDs.
I tried most of the .NET/Powershell classes/WinAPIs provided for monitors data:

WmiMonitorID
Win32_DesktopMonitor
WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams
WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods
EnumDisplayDevices
EnumDisplayMonitors
GetMonitorInfo

Always output just limited ID of manufacturer/name:
Manufacturer: BOE06CB
Monitor name: BOE
But I need full version of Manufacturer ID:
Manufacturer: RMJCY_NV15N42
Monitor name: BOEhydis NV15N42 (Dell RMJCY)
*This problem is not caused by insufficient permissions or with obsolete monitor drivers. If i run on same machine for example AIDA64 software, it throws data in mentioned format correctly.
Does anybody know which .NET class / WinAPI could extract monitor manufacturer ID in full format?
Thank you very much!

If I want to know information about my monitor, I read the sticker on the back of the monitor. The information available likely depends on the driver installed/used. Why do you need to retrieve this information programmatically?

You could try to use WMIC to get the information about your monitor. Refer to the thread: https://superuser.com/a/1245097

@Jeaninez-MSFT: As I already mentioned, the information depends on the driver installed. For example, running wmic desktopmonitor get Caption, MonitorType, MonitorManufacturer, Name (or Win32_DestopMonitor) on my computer results in Generic PnP Monitor. Type: wmic alias desktopmonitor for more info. In the OP, the poster mentioned that he/she/they already tried  Win32_DestopMonitor.

I need to receive this information programmatically because It´s necessary for the software which I´m developing. I´m not sure if the wrong information is caused by installed driver tho - I´m receiving desired output with e.g. AIDA64 software (which is able to get mentioned output as same as Linux hwinfo cmd, using same driver as are using mentioned WMI classes). Seems like problem is in limitation of WMI classes, rather than driver. I think there has to be .NET? class which is able to get these info, which is not that much publicly known. Thanks for reaction both of you tho!

When you run the following code, do you see the info you want?  This is basically a monitor history, which means you will get info on monitors that are no longer attached to the computer. There is also a EDID in this area of the registry, but decoding it would take some effort.  Get-ChildItem 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY' | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_" } | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_" } | ForEach-Object { $_ }

The following may be of interest: In the registry one finds HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY underneath this subkey you'll find some additional subkeys. Expand each on until you find Device Parameters. Then retrieve the value of EDID.  Then see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44046546/10024425, https://github.com/linuxhw/EDID.

Also see https://www.drhdmi.eu/dictionary/edid.html and this

Allright, you were right. HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY actually contains Manufacturer data which I´m looking for - information is only in raw EDID data, concretly in "FE" block. Data is coded in ASCII (hexadecimal) format. I will post here script which is able to extract these raw data, for decoding algorithm i will use resources which you provided, @user246821. Thanks a bunch guys! Zdeneik

$registryPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY"
function ConvertTo-HexString {
param (
[byte[]]$data
)
return -join ($data | ForEach-Object { "{0:X2}" -f $_ })
}
$subKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path $registryPath
foreach ($subKey in $subKeys) {
$monitorKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path $subKey.PSPath
foreach ($monitorKey in $monitorKeys) {
    $edidKeyPath = Join-Path -Path $monitorKey.PSPath -ChildPath "Device Parameters"


if (Test-Path -Path $edidKeyPath) {
$edid = Get-ItemProperty -Path $edidKeyPath -Name "EDID" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($edid) {
            $edidData = ConvertTo-HexString -data $edid.EDID
            Write-Output "Monitor: $($monitorKey.Name)"
            Write-Output "EDID Data: $edidData"
            Write-Output ""
        }
    }
}

}

If you're using C#, then there's no need for PowerShell.  One can use RegistryKey class. Look at Registry.OpenBaseKey, Registry.OpenSubKey,

Registry.GetSubKeyNames, and Registry.GetValue

For bitwise operations and logical operators the following posts may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78723648/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71388371/10024425

Very Basic Information Extraction From EDID:
This code works its way through the registry keys to extract each EDID and returns one PSCustomObject per each monitor found:
foreach ($Display in Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY') {
   foreach ($Monitor in Get-ChildItem $Display.PSPath) {
      foreach ($edid in Get-ItemProperty "$($Monitor.PSPath)\Device Parameters" -Name 'EDID') {
         $bytes = $edid.EDID
         if ($bytes) {
            #  DDDs: Display Descriptor Definitions
            $dddDisplayProductName = ''
            $dddAlphanumeric = ''
            $dddSerialNumber = ''
            #  Loop through each DDD
            for ($i = 54; $i -lt 109; $i += 18) {
               #  Get this DDD's type
               $dddType = $bytes[$i + 3]
               #  Only interested in DDDs of type 252, 254, and 255
               if ($dddType -in 252, 254, 255) {
                  #  Get the old DDD value(s) if any
                  $oldDDD = if ($dddType -eq 252) { $dddDisplayProductName } elseif ($dddType -eq 254) { $dddAlphanumeric } else { $dddSerialNumber }
                  #  Get this DDD value
                  $newDDD = [Text.AsciiEncoding]::new().GetString($bytes[($i + 5)..($i + 17)]).Trim()
                  #  Create an array of this type of DDD if necessary
                  $DDD = if ('' -eq $oldDDD) { $newDDD } elseif ($oldDDD -is [array]) { $oldDDD + $newDDD } else { $oldDDD, $newDDD }
                  #  Save the DDD back to appropriate location
                  if ($dddType -eq 252) { $dddDisplayProductName = $DDD } elseif ($dddType -eq 254) { $dddAlphanumeric = $DDD } else { $dddSerialNumber = $DDD }
               }
            }
            $return = [PSCustomObject]@{
               ManufacturerID        = '{0:X4}' -f [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($bytes, 8)
               ProductIDCode         = '{0:X4}' -f [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($bytes, 10)
               SerialNumber          = '{0:X8}' -f [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($bytes, 12)
               ManufacturerDate      = $(switch ($bytes[16]) {
                     0 { '{0} (Year of Manufacture)' }
                     255 { '{0} (Model Year)' }
                     Default { "Week $($bytes[16]) of {0} (Year of Manufacture)" }
                  }) -f ($bytes[17] + 1990)
               EDID_Version          = 'v{0}.{1}' -f $bytes[18], $bytes[19]
               dddDisplayProductName = $dddDisplayProductName
               dddAlphanumeric       = $dddAlphanumeric
               dddSerialNumber       = $dddSerialNumber
            }
            $return
         }
      }
   }
}

NOTE #1: I'm primarily using this documentation, and it appears that version 1.3 and 1.4 of the EDID are close enough to each other that this code works for both (and both versions appear to be the most common currently in use).
NOTE #2: The structure provides a place for 4 Display Descriptor Definitions per each monitor, but any DDD can be of any type.  This means that a monitor can have more than one DDD of the exact same type.  If you look at the example output below, notice that "dddAlphanumeric" for the first monitor is an array, this is because this monitor had 2 DDDs of type alphanumeric.
Below is the results when ran on my computer:
ManufacturerID        : AE0D
ProductIDCode         : 176E
SerialNumber          : 00000000
ManufacturerDate      : Week 23 of 2019 (Year of Manufacture)
EDID_Version          : v1.4
dddDisplayProductName :
dddAlphanumeric       : {CMN, N173HCE-G33}
dddSerialNumber       :

ManufacturerID        : AC10
ProductIDCode         : 407F
SerialNumber          : 37363753
ManufacturerDate      : Week 27 of 2013 (Year of Manufacture)
EDID_Version          : v1.3
dddDisplayProductName : DELL U2713HM
dddAlphanumeric       :
dddSerialNumber       : 7JNY5375767S

ManufacturerID        : 2D4C
ProductIDCode         : 7103
SerialNumber          : 01000E00
ManufacturerDate      : Week 1 of 2020 (Year of Manufacture) 
EDID_Version          : v1.3
dddDisplayProductName : SAMSUNG
dddAlphanumeric       :
dddSerialNumber       :

This one is my laptop screen, which is why the SerialNumber 00000000.  The serial number is just a number, not the serial number found on the back of the monitor.  Since my laptop cannot have a second screen of this type, the manufacture leaves this empty.  A more sophisticated extraction of info from EDID would lookup the actual name of the manufacturer from ManufacturerID and product info from ProductIDCode.  The week and year appears to match my laptop, an other info is probably correct, but doesn't mean much to me.
ManufacturerID        : AE0D
ProductIDCode         : 176E
SerialNumber          : 00000000
ManufacturerDate      : Week 23 of 2019 (Year of Manufacture)
EDID_Version          : v1.4
dddDisplayProductName :
dddAlphanumeric       : {CMN, N173HCE-G33}
dddSerialNumber       :

This is an old monitor I used to have, which is where you may have an issue: How do you know if you are looking at current info, or past info.  The retrieved info appears correct.
ManufacturerID        : AC10
ProductIDCode         : 407F
SerialNumber          : 37363753
ManufacturerDate      : Week 27 of 2013 (Year of Manufacture)
EDID_Version          : v1.3
dddDisplayProductName : DELL U2713HM
dddAlphanumeric       :
dddSerialNumber       : 7JNY5375767S

This is my current monitor, the info also appears to match what I have.  But, as you can see, each manufacture provides drastically different info, with some giving more info while others giving less.  In this case, you would probably have to lookup the ProductIDCode 7103 for more detailed info.
ManufacturerID        : 2D4C
ProductIDCode         : 7103
SerialNumber          : 01000E00
ManufacturerDate      : Week 1 of 2020 (Year of Manufacture) 
EDID_Version          : v1.3
dddDisplayProductName : SAMSUNG
dddAlphanumeric       :
dddSerialNumber       :

